# JavaScript - List all files url's under dirctory

Tags: javascript

I have a `json` and `image` files in my projecy directory:

```
-project
--index.html
--json
----json01.json
----json02.json
```

I know hot to get the file using `http`, but there us a way to list all files  `url`'s in `json` directory?

accessing local files is impossible- [access-local-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358792/how-can-i-iterate-through-files-in-javascript), but this is also apply on project files/folders?

Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about client side or server side javascript?

Comment: client(where the index, css, etc...).

Comment: the only two ways are to get it is returning it from your server in some way or brute force (which is usually not acceptable :D). JavaScript cannot do it alone

Comment: Yes, I belived that this will be the answer, thanks.

Comment: Question looks like a duplicate of these: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860507/listing-files-of-a-directory-in-a-webpage) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924935/list-files-in-a-directory-using-only-javascript), probably lot of others as well. In short, no, it cannot be done with just client-side javascript.